# Loop Object that has Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to find if an Object has a value? My Object looks like below: I have to loop through the object array and check if any array has "SPOUSE" in its value. if exist set a flag spouseExits = true and store the number (in this case 4) in a variable spouseIndex

```
myObj = {
    "CHIP": [
        "CHILD5"
    ],
    "APTC/CSR": [
        "SELF1",
        "CHILD2",
        "CHILD3",
        "SPOUSE4"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Will the object attributes always be named as they appear in the example? Will the `SPOUSE` value always take the form `SPOUSE<integer>`? Have you looked into using `Array.find` and `String.test`?

Comment: @fubar -- yes the spouse will have an index always. I need to store the index in a separate variable

Comment: I need help. Please don't close. Let me know what is not clear

Comment: Correction, it's `String.match` or `RegExp.test`.

Comment: how do I get into Object's array?

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you already tried. If you have no code and you also don't know how to start I don't think that a copy paste solution from here will help yo, if that's the case then you need to read a little bit more of basic Javascript. If that's not the case, then your code will help us help you.

Comment: @dragonfly All of the feedback you have provided, IE9 support, needing the end number, not the index, how to get the array, etc is information that should have been included in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to create an array of all the strings and then find the element matching `/SPOUSE(\d+)/i` using [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). If it exists, you can get the spouse number from the capturing group. If there's no match, return `-1`.

```js
const myObj = { "CHIP": ["CHILD5"], "APTC/CSR": ["SELF1", "CHILD2", "CHILD3", "SPOUSE4"] }

const regex = /SPOUSE(\d+)/i
const spouse = Object.values(myObj)
  .flat()
  .find((el) => regex.test(el))

const spouseIndex = spouse ? spouse.match(regex)[1] : -1
const spouseExists = spouseIndex != -1
console.log('Spouse exists:', spouseExists)
console.log('Spouse index:', spouseIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't use es6 methods as this has to support ie9 browser

Comment: Use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-flat-polyfill).